Changing "Target to" Via Command Line
In Windows, I am using the command line (batch file) to select a camera and to render my Blender scene. This is done by using this snippet:
"D:\Blender\blender.exe" -b "Cockpit.blend" --python-expr "import bpy; bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.scene.objects.get('CAM_E');" -o "X:\RenderOut\CAM_E" -s 1 -e 250 -a 

Now, I also would like to change the target within a "Target to" condition of an Empty object. I want the Empty to target to my "CAM_E" camera.
How can I do this? Thank you.

You mean you want to have a TrackTo constraint added to your Empty, targeting your camera? Or you want your camera to track to the empty? I'm not sure what you mean by '"Target to" condition of an Empty object'

The Empty already has a TrackTo constraint in my scene. I just want to change it via command line, e.g. in pseudo code: Empty.TrackTo("CAM_E");
I have one blend file with different cameras. So I run the batch with different selected cameras (see snippet above), e.g. "CAM_A", "CAM_B", ....
Now I also want to swap the "TrackTo" targets via command line.

I would just put this script:
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C

#Get the target object and scene camera
target_obj = D.objects['Target']
camera = C.scene.camera

#create a new constraint
tt = camera.constraints.new("TRACK_TO")

#or get one named "Track To" 
#tt = camera.constraints['Track To']

#Then set the target on the modifier
tt.target = target_obj


into it's own script like "C:/Desktop/my_script.py" and then replace this bit in your command line:
--python-expr "import bpy; bpy.context.scene.camera =bpy.context.scene.objects.get('CAM_E');"

with this:
-p "C:/Desktop/my_script.py"

And I believe that should work.
If you enable Developer Extras and Python Tooltips in your preferences then almost every data block will show you how to access it when you hover over it.

